# Cartesian product of 2 dimensional

Tags: products, direct-product

Let $R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,2),(4,1)\}$. Then how can I calculate $R\times R$?

Comment: If that's simpler, try to do the same first for the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$. Then just replace $a$ by $(1,1)$, $b$ by $(2,2,)$, and so on. These are just some objects that are in the set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cartesian product of cartesian products?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096073/what-is-the-cartesian-product-of-cartesian-products)

Comment: Just revise the definition of cartesian product. It doesn't matter if the element are ordered pairs themselves, the definition applies as usual.

Comment: Have you now clarified your doubts on that point?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is the set of all ordered pair therefore

$$R\times R=\{((1,1),(2,2)),((1,1),(3,2)),\ldots\}$$

with $|R\times R|=16$.

Comment: Questions like this shouldn't be answered, we should first check if they are duplicates. A short google search found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096073/what-is-the-cartesian-product-of-cartesian-products

Comment: @5xum We can find the definition of cartesian product almost in every math source and not only on MSE. I gave a link to the wiki page to review the definition but your link is also very useful for the asker. In that case I suppose that the asker was confused by the fact that the elements of $R$ themselves are ordered pairs and that he/she was looking for a specific help on that point.

Comment: In my linked question, the asker was confused by the exact same fact, i.e. that the elements of the sets of the product are themselves ordered pairs. I think this is a clear example of a duplicate question.

Comment: @5xum That's fine, you have made a good service to give that reference too and to indicate that as a duplicate.